# Can you use sagemaker Python libraries on my localhost?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am interested if one can import sagemaker packages on your own local Python environment or whether they are restricted to AWS Sagemaker?

```
from sagemaker_automl import AutoMLInteractiveRunner, AutoMLLocalCandidate
```

For instance can I somehow download the sagemaker_automl?

I know the there are no sagemaker packages available in the conda repository. Perhaps there is some other way to get them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Sagemaker Python SDK is [open source and on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk), as well as published on [Pypi](https://pypi.org/project/sagemaker/).

You can install it by running:

```sh
pip install sagemaker
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer do you maybe know if it is possible to run Sagemaker on Windows as well?

Comment: @BorutFlis according to the documentation the SDK is supported only on Unix/Linux and Mac systems. If you’re on a Windows machine, your best bets are WSL 2, Docker, VM (in this order).